# How to add columns filter using react-bootstrap/table?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table, tablefilter

I want to add the ability to sort/filter the columns of my table. On the web I can't find any example on how to do that with react-bootstrap/table.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';

export default class Success extends React.Component {
render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">         
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <Table striped bordered hover>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>#</th>
                          <th>Label</th>
                          <th>Text</th>
                          <th>Prediction</th>                                                                     
                          <th>Validation</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {Object.keys(this.state.jsondata.label).map(k =>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{k}</td>
                                <td>{this.state.jsondata.label[k]}</td>
                                                        
                                <td>{this.state.jsondata.prediction[k]}</td>
                                <td>
                                 <Button variant="danger" size="sm" onClick={() => { this.removeData(k) }}>Cancel<XOctagonFill/></Button>
                                </td>                                
                            </tr>
                        )}                  
                      </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I can't find any ressource about how to add filters to the column without using react-bootstrap-table2 but then I need to modify my whole project

Comment: you need to implement your own inputs inside the table headers. if you provide us a codesandbox, i think i can alter it a little bit to show you how

Comment: @Apostolos do you have access to it ? https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-poitras-tnb6z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: yes. let me check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a very minimal example on how to filter array based on column value.

You create an input text inside the `th` and then use this value as a property filter.
Then, it's your choice if you want to do string comparisons based on equality or `startsWith` or `includes` etc

Please check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-paper-41hvc)